# How to have VS Code's quick action to suggest me to convert ESM to CJS?

Tags: visual-studio-code, es6-modules, cjs

I would like to use ESM actually, but since [I'm unable to make Jest work with ESM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76698752/3416774), my only option is to use CJS. Since occasionally my code has ESM, especially when copying from the internet (even Jest's docs occasionally have ESM code), I want VS Code suggest me to convert ESM to CJS, not the other way around. Is there a way to do so?

[image]